# While exporting/converting to CSV, replace first line with newline

Tags: excel, vba, csv

EDIT: I CHANGED THIS ORIGINAL POST SO I COULD EMBED THE FINAL CODE I WENT WITH. 
Using the code at the bottom to export a specific worksheet and convert to a CSV file.
The output file will consistently have the very first line beginning with a blank space followed by the string

```
,,Primary,Secondary,Tertiary
```

I would like to remove/replace that line with a newline. i.e..
CURRENT:

```
 ,,Primary,Secondary,Tertiary
100,106,2165483624,2165483624,8133181331
```

I would like to remove/replace that top line with a newline. i.e:

```
(newline here)
100,106,2165483624,2165483624,8133181331
```

---

That line will always be the first line, and will be the only line beginning with a space and two commas, also the only one with the words Primary,Secondary,Tertiary comma-delimited. 
I've spent several hours checking this site and others but either
I'm using the wrong keywords or my desired outcome hasn't been
documented yet. Thanks in advance.

---

### CODE I ENDED UP USING IS BELOW

Sub btn_Export_to_CSV_Click()

```
Dim csvFilePath As String
Dim fileNo As Integer
Dim fileName As String
Dim oneLine As String
Dim lastRow, lastCol As Long
Dim idxRow, idxCol As Long
' --- get this file name (without extension)
fileName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1)
' --- create file name of CSV file (with full path)
csvFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileName & ".csv"
' --- get last row and last column
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
' --- open CSC file
fileNo = FreeFile
Open csvFilePath For Output As #fileNo
Print #fileNo, ""   ' -- write one blank line
' --- row loop
For idxRow = 2 To lastRow
    oneLine = ""
    ' --- column loop: concatenate oneLine
    For idxCol = 1 To lastCol
        If (idxCol = 1) Then
            oneLine = Cells(idxRow, idxCol).Value
        Else
            oneLine = oneLine & "," & Cells(idxRow, idxCol).Value
        End If
    Next
    ' --- write oneLine > CSV file
    Print #fileNo, oneLine  ' -- Print: no quotation (output oneLine as it is)
Next
' --- close file
Close #fileNo
MsgBox "CSV file completed !!" & Chr(13) & csvFilePath
```

End Sub

Comment: I tried your code and didn't find any space and comma before the visible contents /columns ( while there are some commas after the visible contents). So I don't know what problem exactly you are facing. But you can  deal with the csv file as plain txt file, and load the file in excel, and then replace the first line.

Comment: Phil, the conversion of the selected worksheet leaves a space and 2 commas because the header has 2 empty cells, then says Primary Secondary Tertiary. Below that the data begins. The point is, I don't want the header at all, and as stated, I'm trying to automate the removal of the header if possible so I dont have to manually open/edit a file every time I make a change, and export, which is frequently.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: I ended up modifying the worksheet and going with code that's a bit different. End result is the same, but the CSV worksheet must not have any blank lines above the PRIMARY SECONDARY TERTIARY entries. I'll put the final code in my original comment in case someone needs it. Thanks for your help